# How to read this tag, what language is it?

Tags: php

I'm working on a website, that was done by someone else previously. Owner didn't end up with previous dev on a good terms and I cant contact him now with questions.

For most of part, code is a regular PHP. However, in some places I see weird tags that I cant recognize.

for example:

```
<php:dropdownlist:ddlTypeOfResidence></php:dropdownlist:ddlTypeOfResidence>
```

The code above, generates the dropdown with values. I don't understand how to read this tag, on the sidebar, they have the get a quote form, and I need to add this field on that sidebar form. I copy pasted the line given above, and it works only on pages, where the original form exists that includes that line as well.

Example, page freeQuote has a form, and on that page on sidebar, get a free quote mini form is also displayed. On this page, input field gets the values dynamically, so that TAG works on this page...

On the other pages, where the original full form is not loaded, this dropdown is still displayed on the sidebar mini form, however, the values are empty.

Anyways, before everything else, I need to understand what language / tag is that, how to read it.

Comment: It's not a widely standardised tag. Likely a self-invented placeholder which is handled via a `str_replace` or so.

Comment: It looks like some sort of templating engine is parsing the code. [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) would be one example but their syntax does not look like that.

Comment: Are you able to identify any of the software installed on the server? PHP, ASP, ColdFusion?

Comment: do a search in all the project files for this `function dropdownlist(` and/or `"ddlTypeOfResidence"`

Comment: `Language=PHP:Function=dropdownlist:ObjectUsedForIteration=ddlTypeOfResidence` is my best guess

Comment: Thanks for answers everyone.

@AlexAndrei  search on "function dropdownlist" on whole website, gives nothing at all, so I guess, its not the case.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  website itself uses good amount of PHP, but because of the tags like that, I thought there was something else involved, I was thinking about Pearl, but I guess I was wrong.

most of the files where these weird tags appear to be, are .tpl files.

Comment: I had a hunch this would be the case. `.tpl` is most commonly used for templating files. If you check out [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines) and sort the *Languages* column then you can try Googling the syntax for the PHP templating engines. If this is too cumbersome then I would search for folders on the server which may elude to the engine being used. If this is a custom engine built by the developer then I would recommend porting it to a supported engine if it fits into the owner's budget.

Comment: One more suggestion would be to see if you can figure out where the `.tpl` files are being included in the PHP code. This might give you some clues about where to search. So if you've found `about_us.tpl` then try and track down the code which is including it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a basic XML converter. The below code is actually a XML code:

```
<php:dropdownlist:ddlTypeOfResidence></php:dropdownlist:ddlTypeOfResidence>
```

What it does is: It parses `php:dropdownlist:ddlTypeOfResidence` string using `.split(':')` and does the needed functionality accordingly.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it is not PHP parsing this XML code? It might help OP out if you could identify a few templating engines which use `.split(':')`

Comment: There isn't any open source templating engine that produces this XML code. What you can do is you can indeed write your own parser for this purpose, using any language you want.

Comment: I've found a similar templating engine for PHP http://www.hyperkit-software.com/projects/phptemplates/index.html

Comment: Thanks for answers everyone. I really appreciate your help. 

@Yagiz  you were right, I found out this is custom parser, its just the way whole backend and framework is written, is very deep linked and messy. But your directions gave me some ideas that lead me to solutions. Thank you :))

Comment: Not a problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a template engine that change some tags into native PHP renders.

I don't know if it's a regular engine ( maybe a custom engine ), but most powerful and simple PHP engine is Smarty. ( This isn't Smarty )

You can look at the PHP codes hope that you find the engine.

Good Luck